# Bayesian parameter optimization of a Voight matrix

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, parameterization

I have constructed  a finite element model of a musical instrument. The physical properties of the wood were very difficult to obtain and as they are anisotropic they need all 3 dimensions. I am trying to improve my estimate of the 9 parameters of the input Voight matrix by Bayesian parameter estimation. I need to know, preferably by seeing an worked example or a reference to something equivalent, how to set this up effectively in say MATLAB or equivalent. I have a prior distribution and the results of over 100 parameter estimates from the FEM, but have no inverse mechanism to adjust the learning experience to suggest new input parameters. Is this possible and if so any suggestions please.
Thanks for any help or insights.

Comment: This post doesn’t contain a question. Can you [edit] your question to clarify what it is that you're asking for? It seems that you're looking for some kind of a reference about a Voight matrix. What specifically do you want to learn from this reference? Also, please give your post a more informative title.

Comment: Thank you. Have posted amended question.